# should I put a semi-colon after a single PHP statement?

Tags: php

e.g.

```
some html....
<p class="date"><?php echo $date; ?></p>
more html...
```

?

Comment: No,  The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block. The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It might be better to always use a semi-colon :

- Lowers the probability of errors
  if you need to extend your code in
  the specific section.
- Improves readability of code

Comment: As a Python fan, I strongly disagree with "improves readability of code". Newlines, indentation and a good coding style improve readability. Semicolons are needed only because the PHP interpreter or IDE parser needs them.

Comment: as a sublime-text fan i strongly agree with "improves readability of code" because with standard html/php markup-sugar this is getting marked as error and ongoing code is not readable ;)

Comment: As a bananas *fan*, i'm strongly ambivalent about things that are not banana related, as it should be. As a PHP *developer* (more than just a fan) i strongly prefer semicolons to terminate all lines as a matter of style consistency, clarity of intent, and a kind of self-check that the code is accurate.

Answer (score 8):

I find that not doing so can:

1. Break syntax highlighting in some editors / IDE (not critical, but annoying)
2. Make code harder to maintain.

So yes, I recommend doing so, unless you are sure short tags are fine for the server config in which case its not really relevant.

When editing other people's stuff, I try to just follow the same style.

Answer (score 4):

This particular little idiosyncrasy is discussed in the [instruction separation manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php).

The bottom line is that it's not enforced either way, so it's left up to the programmer.  It's a decent item to touch on in any sort of PHP coding standard, but as far as standards go, it's a relatively minor issue.

Personally, I have started always using a trailing semi-colon.  It's easier on your IDE, and helps avoid those quick little parse errors when you jump into a template and start appending code (especially in a verbose template, that might not have user-friendly line wrapping).

Answer (score 1):

It's really up to you. I do, as it helps me with code readability.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend it, if for no other reason than it's a good habit to get into, like properly indenting html.