# how can i change this mysql code to pdo?

Tags: mysql, pdo

i have this code in iclude for connect to database 
i have in this file mysql connection function too but i decide change mysql to pdo
-include.php:

```
try{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename', 'username', 'password');
    return $conn;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'can not connect to database';
    exit();
}
```

i have mysql query in index.php but i want change this code to pdo

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT id,col1 FROM tblname ORDER BY col4 DESC, col3 DESC, tzade DESC LIMIT 18");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)) {
$j=0;
    while($result = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {

$j++;
if($result->id == $site_id){
?>
<a class="normal_link" href="l.php?lid=<?php echo $result->id; ?>&title=<?php echo title($result->col1);?>">
<div id="jadv">
<div><?php echo $j; ?></div>
<div><?php echo $result->col1; ?></div>
</div>
</a>
<?php
}
else{
?>
<a class="normal_link" href="l.php?lid=<?php echo $result->id; ?>&title=<?php echo title($result->col1);?>">
<div id="jadva">
<div id="jad"><?php echo $j; ?></div>
<div id="jad"><?php echo $result->col1; ?></div>
</div>
</a>
<?php
}
}
}
?>
```

how can i change mysql query in this code to pdo?

Comment: Why are you returning inside a simple `try {}` block?

Comment: i am beginner , help me with other suggest

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id,col1 FROM tblname ORDER BY col4 DESC, col3 DESC, tzade DESC LIMIT 18 ";
$sth = $conn->query($sql);
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($count = $sth->rowCount() > 0){
$j=0;
    while ($row = $sth->fetch()) {

$j++;
if($row['id'] == $site_id){
?>
<a class="normal_link" href="l.php?lid=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>&title=<?php echo title($row['col1']);?>">
<div id="jadv">
<div><?php echo $j; ?></div>
<div><?php echo $row['col1'] ?></div>
</div>
</a>
<?php
}
else{
?>
<a class="normal_link" href="l.php?lid=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>&title=<?php echo title($row['col1']);?>">
<div id="jadva">
<div id="jad"><?php echo $j; ?></div>
<div id="jad"><?php echo $row['col1'] ?></div>
</div>
</a>
<?php
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You get the results from the select?

Comment: i find problem i use select without "" 
but $row['id'] === $site_id not detect and i change === to == and worked

Comment: is it important use ; after $row[] ?

Comment: Ok, sorry, The operator == casts between two different types if they are different, while the === operator performs a 'typesafe comparison'. That means that it will only return true if both operands have the same type and the same value. So if you compares a integer with a string 1 === "1" this always returns false.

Comment: Is optional in this case but.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544792/should-i-put-a-semi-colon-after-a-single-php-statement

Comment: can you help me in this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061658/change-mysql-to-pdo-and-store-result-in-variable

Answer (score 0):

1. Read some tutorial (there are plenty even [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info))
2. Run some simple queries to make yourself familiar with PDO
3. Start with rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

You should read some doc about PDO and do some tutorial. But to help you, here is a really simple sample to begin with PDO :

```
<?php
$connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$PARAM_hote;dbname=$PARAM_db_name", $PARAM_user, $PARAM_pwd); // DB connexion

$results=$connection->query("SELECT member FROM member ORDER BY member ASC"); // retrieving all entries from member table 
$results->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); // retrieving results as objects
while( $lines= $results->fetch() ) // retrieving list of member
{
        echo 'user: '.$lines->member.'<br />'; // displaying members
}
$results->closeCursor(); // close results cursor
?>
```

And here a more sophisticated one with params (prepared query) :

```
<?php
// connection opening ...

$prepared_query=$connecion->prepare("SELECT id FROM member WHERE member_id= :id"); // query prepare
$prepared_query->execute(array( 'id' => 1 ));
$lines=$prepared_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo $lines->id.'<br />';
?>
```

It's an old sample of mine I hope will help you.