# change mysql to pdo and store result in variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

how can i change mysql code to pdo and store results in variabel

i use this code in index.php content:

```
$games_sql = mysql_query("SELECT id,col1,col2,now FROM tblname ORDER BY now ASC LIMIT 9");
$gn=0;
while($game_get=mysql_fetch_array($games_sql))
{
$id = $game_get['id'];
$col1= $game_get['col1'];
$col2= $game_get['col2'];
$now = $game_get['now'];
$gametimeanddate = jdate("l d M y time G:i",$now);
$gamedate = jdate("l d M y",$now);
$gametime = jdate("G:i",$now);
$gn++;
if(($gn%2)==0){
    $class='background-color:#EEE'; , ..... ?>
```

and use this variables:

```
<?php echo $id;?>&title=<?php echo func1($col1).'-'.func1($col2);?>
```

and pdo connection include content:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname
```

i want change my query to pdo and store query result to variables and use that in php codes

Comment: There are any number of PDO tutorials on the web.  Try one out and show that you have made the effort.  If you are getting stuck on some specific aspect of converting to PDO, then ask a specific question about that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$games_sql = "SELECT id,col1,col2,now FROM tblname ORDER BY now ASC LIMIT 9";
$sth = $conn->query($games_sql);
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$gn=0;
while ($game_get = $sth->fetch()) {

$id = $game_get['id'];
$col1 = $game_get['col1'];
$col2 = $game_get['col2'];
$now = $game_get['now'];

$gametimeanddate = jdate("l d M y time G:i",$now);
$gamedate = jdate("l d M y",$now);
$gametime = jdate("G:i",$now);

//SAVE VALUES IN ARRAY
$items[] = array('id' => $id, 'col1' => $col1, 'col2' => $col2, 'now' => $now, 'gametimeanddate' => $gametimeanddate, 'gamedate' => $gamedate, 'gametime' => $gametime); 

$gn++;

    if(($gn%2)==0){
        $class='background-color:#EEE';
    }
}
?>
```

USE ARRAY VALUES EXAMPLE:

```
<?php
echo '<table>';
    foreach($items as $value)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'. $value['id'] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $value['col1'] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $value['col2'] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $value['gametimeanddate'] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $value['gamedate'] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $value['gametime'] .'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
?>
```

WITH YOUR EXAMPLE:

```
<?php
foreach($items as $value)
{
    echo $value['id']?>&title=<?php echo func1($value['col1']).'-'.func1($value['col2']);
}
?>
```

**PDO:**

A couple of nice tutorials to learn some basics about PDO

[NetTuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

[phpro](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)

**EDIT:**

You could extract your array values to variables. Example:

```
<?php

$items = array("color" => "blue", "size"  => "medium", "shape" => "sphere");

extract($items);

echo $color;

?>
```

With your example you just need

```
extract($game_get);
```

Comment: thank you but we use array
i want use varibale replace array in echo

Comment: @Mohammadb You could use extract to put array values to variables, see EDIT part in my answer..

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is [fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php), just like mysql and mysqli.

Comment: You sure do. I gave you the link to them.

Comment: a short example go's a long way. Sometimes further then a detailed php.net page